# Transmission to glass

Tags: glass

[image][image][image][image]Hi Blender StackExchange, can you help? I'm currently trying to create glass from a solid object by turning transmission up to 1.0. The rendered image I'm getting is a solid dark grey and not transparent at all. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Blender on Stack Exchange.  It would be extra helpful if you can upload a sample blend file and/or some screenshots of your material setup to help us solve this.

Comment: Thanks Merlin, screen grab added. Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So "this just works" when rendering with Cycles, but Eevee requires a bit more setup.

Try the following settings:

1. Render → Screen Space Reflections ON
2. Render → Screen Space Reflections → Refraction ON
3. Material → Surface → Principled BSDF → Transmission 1.000
4. Material → Surface → Principled BSDF → Roughness [Cycles Only]
5. Material → Settings → Blend Mode OPAQUE [or ADDITIVE]
6. Material → Settings → Screen Space Refraction ON
7. Material → Settings → Refraction Depth PLAY WITH IT

You can also check out the documentation for:

- [Principled BSDF shader node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html)
- [Eeve materials settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html)

You should get something like this in *Render Mode*, I didn't have the patience to model a teacup, so the default cube is all you get :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Merlin, it certainly looks better but it's still pretty weird. Is there a way I can share another screen grab with this response on StackExchange do you know?

Comment: @RhonaHayes I see you managed to edit your question and add another.  You are in Look Dev mode (see spheres in top right of viewport) you want Render Mode

Comment: I am in lock dev mode, as it looks so much better than render mode. See new edit above.

Comment: @RhonaHayes join me [in the 2.80 chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/99958/blender-2-80)

Comment: bing to the o. Except what's the difference in my shadow?
Also please can I get help with one more thing Merlin? 
As you can't copy an object over to another Blender doc, can you please tell me how to take off/reset whatever I've weirdness I've managed to appy to my model so that I can apply this new set? Or do I just start again?

Comment: Yes you can, just go to File -> Append and browse to the blend file you want.  You can do this in either direction so you could copy your material over or the teacup mesh.

Comment: thank you for the links. They're very informative.

Comment: No problem, I'll be loitering in the chat room, so if you have any more issues then the link is above.  If the problem is resolved then please accept the answer so others know that this question is closed.

Comment: [Denoising is only available for cycles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/denoising.html)

Comment: Aha! Brilliant! 
I can't chat in the chatroom until I have 20 reputation but I have a few more questions. Is there I way I can ask them?

Comment: You should start a new question.  You may also find that somebody has asked the same before so use the search box at the top first.  I tried to override so you could join chat but it won't let me for the reason you shared.